# WPF Listview: Aranging the Headers vertically

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So i think this is quite an easy thing, but i really don't know how to get it done.

I Want a Listview instead of this:

```
Name|Age|Sex
Bob|30|Male
```

being aranged like this:

```
Name|Bob
Age|30
Sex|Male
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tomershamam/archive/2008/09/22/lt-howto-gt-replace-listview-columns-with-rows-lt-howto-gt.aspx) by Tomer Shamam. I think this is what you are trying to achieve.